# Find all paths starting from a source node using BFS

Tags: algorithm, networkx, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I have a directed graph, and i wrote a code to find all paths from a starting node using bfs algorithm. Here is my code:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_path([1, 2])
G.add_path([1, 3])
G.add_path([2, 7])
G.add_path([3, 4])
G.add_path([4, 2])
G.add_path([4, 6])
G.add_path([5, 2])
G.add_path([6, 5])
G.add_path([7, 8])
G.add_path([8, 9])
G.add_path([8, 10])

def bfs(G, s):
    q = queue.Queue()
    visited = []
    q.put(s)
    visited.append(s)
    while not q.empty():
        v = q.get()
        for node in G.neighbors(v):
            if node not in visited:
                q.put(node)
                visited.append(node)
    print(visited)

bfs(G, 3)
```

The problem with the algorithm is that i can find all the nodes that will be visited from the starting node but i cant save(print) every path which i found. How can i modify my algorithm to implement that?

Comment: Do you want *all* paths or a single path for every reachable node?

Comment: I need to find all paths from the starting node

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/

Comment: From the starting node to every other node? Or just to a single node?

Comment: From starting node to every other final node. With final node i mean a node without neighbor. So i need all paths from a starting node